# Is AppObservable a MUST for android?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, dagger, rx-android

In an android app , is **AppObservable** a MUST for each observable ?

I have a **retrofit** generated Observable , injected by **Dagger** :

```
public class UserInfoFragment extends Fragment {
 @Inject
 Observable<User> user;
}
```

In this example

should I override the 'user' in the `onViewCreated()` like this ?

```
this.user = AppObservable.bindFragment(this , user);
```

Moreover , if I don't inject Observable directly , instead , I inject `an Object containing an Observable` :

```
@Inject
CachedValue<User> cachedUser;
```

And in the CachedValue , there is an Observable (other fields skipped) :

```
public class CachedValue<T> {
  public Observable<T> getObservable() {
    return networkObservable.startWith(localObservable).take(1);
  }
}
```

Should I replace this Observable with **AppObservable lifted Observable** ?

```
AppObservable.bindFragment(this , cachedUser.getObservable());
```

All these codes run flawlessly without AppObservable in the simulator (I did unsubscribe these subscriptions in `onDestroyView()` ), but I don't know in real situation is it enough ? Will there be any memory leak after long run ?

In the rx-android's sample project , I saw AppObservable everywhere. But I don't know how to handle injected Observables (or objects containing Observables) correctly .

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think AppObservable is a must.

If you check [AppObservable source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/0.x/rxandroid/src/main/java/rx/android/app/AppObservable.java), it's pretty clear that AppObservable helps ensure that no item will be forwarded to a fragment after it's already destroyed/detached.

From my understanding, you can call isUnsubscribed before emitting an item along with unsubscribing subscriptions in onDestroyView. That should be suffice.

See also:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/127 (You probably read this but just for future reference.)

Comment: It seems  AppObservable is for Observables initialized inside the Activity / Fragment . With Observables maintained / injected by DI frameworks (such as Dagger) , it is not so useful. Is this correct ?

Comment: AppObservable is for Activity and Fragment. Dagger doesn't take care of unsubscribed though. You can also check u2020 on Github. I think is a good start for architecting apps with Dagger and RxAndroid.